# Is there a way to invert all colors on the page with a button click, using jQuery and/or CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I'm hoping to invert all the colors on the page on a button click, and I haven't learned to invert colors. Is there some way to achieve this with a jQuery or JS method, e.g:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $(body).invert()
}
```

or do I have to go through the CSS method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with CSS:

```
body.invert {
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/invert

Just toggle class `.invert` with JS click.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Deykun. If I understand your instructions correctly: I add that code to my CSS, then in my JS, call `$("#button").click(function(){$("#.invert").toggle()})` ?

Comment: Ah, disregard. I succeeded with JS `$("#button").click(function() {
  $("body").css("filter", "invert(1)")
})`. Thanks for your help!